# Combine plots in Maxima

Tags: graphing-functions, maxima-software

I want to combine the following plots as one output figure:

```
plotdf(4*y/x+x*sqrt(y),[trajectory_at,1,1],[x,0,4],[y,0,10])
plot2d(1/4*x^4*(log(x)+2)^2,[x,0,4],[y,0,10])
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are plotdf and plot2d different kinds of plots?

Comment: Yes, I just want to check if that trajectory of the differential equation coincides with the graph of the function. In Sage for example, it's possible to combine different plots to one output figure by the operation `+`.

Comment: I haven't used Maxima more than a few times. In Mathematica (similar program) there's a graphics command something like Display, but one has to already have the graphs to display made, and there's some syntax for it (which I'd have to look up in help for that command...)